# usage of libsvm: all the predicted labels are the same

Tags: libsvm

I'm trying to use libsvm to train a classifier on the following dataset:

(1) The number of class -1 are the same as the number of class 1

(2) The feature value has been scaled to [-1 1]

(3) I've tried 
model = svmtrain(labels, examples, '-t 0');
model = svmtrain(labels, examples);
svm_parameter_selection(labels, examples); //this function is wrote by myself which searches the logc and logg and return the best.

All of these returned models are used to classify the test data. The label of the test data is always 1. 
I use these models to classify the train data (examples in the above functions), the label is still always 1.

[image]